# Push value into array without filling (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Is there a way to give a specific index, in an array, a value. In PHP, I could just do this $arr[index] = val;

Right now, I use

```
Array.prototype.insert = function (index, item) {
  this.splice(index, 0, item);
};
```

And

```
var mute = [];
mute.insert(index, 'value');
```

But, if the array is empty, the index will still be 0. How do I get the right index?

Comment: In the event of an empty array what do you want the function to do? Presumably you can test the array length (`this.length`) and do something different in that event. Without telling us what you want to happen it's difficult to provide specific, or useful, advice without lots of guessing. How do you define "*the right index*"?

Comment: " the index will still be 0" - exactly, because an array indexes start with `0`

Comment: `var arr = []; arr[10]="sparse";`. Here you have a sparse array of `arr.length == 11; // true` with only one defined item at index position 10 and the rest is `undefined`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `object[index] = some_value;`? You can always use Object.keys(object) to iterate over the indexes. Arrays should be continuous (or whatever name it's called), not sparse, and that's what you have all the array methods for. Or you can implement your own version of `Array`, keeping track of all the indexes inside it, with desired functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

`var mute = [];
mute[index] = 'value';`

Comment: if we do `mute[10] = 'value'` on the empty array, its length will become `11`. Is  it the thing the OP wants?

Comment: Correct. There's no other option to achieve 'give a specific index' otherwise we are discussing an Object such as Java's Map interface. The following would do that trick
var mute = {};
mute[index] = 'value';